# How can a pattern be found in a series of Numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

In the given series of numbers (0-9) or a similar series of numbers, How can a pattern be searched?

> 3
>   2
>   4
>   8
>   0
>   8
>   7
>   3
>   8
>   7
>   0
>   0
>   4
>   9
>   6
>   3
>   9
>   7
>   4
>   5
>   7
>   3
>   9
>   6
>   6
>   6
>   7
>   1
>   6
>   3
>   4
>   7
>   7
>   4
>   5
>   1
>   4
>   9
>   3
>   3
>   7
>   9
>   3
>   3
>   9
>   1
>   3
>   0
>   4
>   8
>   0
>   1
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   2
>   8
>   2
>   7
>   4
>   2
>   4
>   6
>   2
>   1
>   0
>   1
>   8
>   4
>   8
>   6
>   2
>   0
>   5
>   9
>   8
>   7
>   7
>   5
>   8
>   8
>   6
>   6
>   6
>   9
>   2
>   6
>   6
>   2
>   8
>   2
>   7
>   8
>   8
>   9
>   7
>   9
>   7
>   7
>   3
>   5
>   2
>   7
>   6
>   6
>   8
>   4
>   2
>   5
>   4
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   8
>   3
>   3
>   6
>   9
>   8
>   6
>   1
>   5
>   8
>   8
>   6
>   3
>   1
>   6
>   7
>   2
>   3
>   8
>   4
>   0
>   5
>   4
>   3
>   8
>   3
>   4
>   9
>   8
>   5
>   5
>   8
>   4
>   2
>   6
>   6
>   3
>   2
>   5
>   0
>   9
>   7
>   2
>   0
>   6
>   6
>   0
>   8
>   6
>   9
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   6
>   8
>   0
>   8
>   4
>   6
>   6
>   5

Is there an algorithm for the same or can an algorithm be written?

Up-till now have been able to check the frequency of the numbers before and after a given number and check for chances of it re-appearing in series.The Patterns to seek could be Arithmetic Sequences,Geometric sequences,Special Sequences, Square numbers, Cube numbers, Fibonacci numbers, etc.

It's been done in excel as my mathematics is the greatest.

```
Sub Tester()
Dim arr, r, b, a

arr = Range("A1:A20").Value
Range("D4").Resize(10, 10).ClearContents
Range("D17").Resize(10, 10).ClearContents

For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1
b = arr(r, 1)
a = arr(r + 1, 1)

With Range("D4")
    .Offset(b, a).Value = .Offset(b, a).Value + 1
End With

With Range("D17")
    .Offset(a, b).Value = .Offset(a, b).Value + 1
End With

Next r

End Sub
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's called *Interpolation*.

Comment: You can always use [Lagrange Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Although the result is often huge.

Comment: The Fourier Transform can find patterns that repeat every $N$ digits

Comment: The first thing you should do is figure out the source of this sequence. Is this 
a crypotext? does this come from an experiment? is it a sample from some specific source which you have received data before? If this is a cryptotext, you perform statistical analysis. If this come from some model, you use characteristic of that model to limit the possible form. If you have previous data of same source, you train a neural network w/ previous data and throw the new data to the NN. What should be done varies case by case.

Comment: 'Autocorrelation' might be the term you are looking for.

Comment: The given sequence seems to be human generated random numbers using keyboards. The distribution of $0$-$9$ follows the pattern in fig 2b of [this paper](http://www.ieice.org/proceedings/NOLTA2005/HTMLS/paper/5060.pdf)

Comment: Some how I missed all the comments before editing. Thank you all for inputs. will go through all suggestions.